# Not uploading .mov but uploads .mp4 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, ios9

Uploading .mp4 video file on server successfully, but .mov isn't uplaoding. It is not being converted to NSData.

Below is the code i am trying.

```
 for index in 0..<User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryVideos.count
        {
            let strVidName = "vid" + String(index) // + ".mov"

            let videoURL = User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryVideos.objectAtIndex(index) as? NSURL

            do {
                let video =  NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL!)
                print("video", video)
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: video! as NSData, name: "video_path[]", fileName: strVidName, mimeType: "video/quicktime")
            }
        }
```

when i set mime type to video/mp4 then working fine if video type also mp4 but for .mov file it doesn't work.
Please guide. Thanks